# Docker-compose migrating from links to networking MongoDB database issue

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am trying to migrate by Dockerfile from using links to networking but I am experiencing some problems. I will first sketch my original setup:

**Original - Links**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD docker_micro_maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb/micros", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
mongodb:
 image: mongo
employee:
 image: jdruwe/docker_micro_maven
 links:
  - mongodb
 ports:
  - "8080"
```

**New - Networking**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD docker_micro_maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://${MONGO_URI_DOCKER}/micros", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
mongodb:
 container_name: "db"
 image: mongo
employee:
 image: jdruwe/docker_micro_maven
 environment:
  - MONGO_URI_DOCKER=db:27017
 ports:
  - "8080"
```

When I called my rest endpoint in the spring boot app (original situation) I always got a response (some json data). When I call it now I get the following error response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1453405937191,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException",
  "message": "Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=db:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: db: unknown error}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=db:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: db: unknown error}}]",
  "path": "/employee"
}
```

The video from Devoxx I used as reference: https://youtu.be/aSATsLG59Zs?t=53m33s

It seems that I keep doing something wrong but I am not really sure what it is, any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you started compose with the `--x-networking` option? Also, without links, the order in which containers are started is not guaranteed, so it's possible the request is made before the mongodb container is up, and ready to accept connections. Note that in Docker Compose 1.6, the new networking is no longer experimental, but you need to use the 2.0 format or the docker-compose file, see https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.0-rc1

Comment: --x-networking did the trick, I really need to start using the --help command. I am using "Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5" and docker-compose version 1.5.2, build e5cf49d. Can I upgrade my docker-compose and keep my docker at that version?

Comment: I think you can, but more enhancements are coming in docker 1.10 that docker compose can make use of, so ideally you should upgrade them both when released

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker-compose 1.5.x, the new networking is still an experimental feature that needs to be enabled using the `--x-networking` option.

The new networking features will be moved out of experimental in docker-compose 1.6 and are automatically used if the new (2.0) file format is used for your docker-compose.yml.

Read the release notes of docker-compose 1.6-rc1 for more information;
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.6.0-rc1